# Reject element from array in efficient way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

My array is

```
 arr = ["wow what", "what anice", "anice day.currently", "day.currently i", "i am", "am in", "in delhi", "delhi but", "but in", "in night", "night i", "i am", "am going", "going to", "to us"]
    arr.each do |el|
     if !el.match('in') && !el.match('is').blank?
      fresh_arr << el
     end
```

but i have 110k element array and it give 8sec that,s too much time can i do this any another way

Thx

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if

Comment: `String#include?` is 2-10 times as fast as `String#match`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `delete_if`

```
arr.delete_if do |e|
  e.match('in') && e.match('is').blank?
end
arr
```

Comment: I think you meant delete_if

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
arr.reject { |i| i.match('in') || i.match('is').blank? }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all elements you need by doing this

```
arr.select{|el| !el.match('in') && !el.match('is').blank?}
```